# Word meaning: "to make one reconsider"

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, phrase-requests

I am looking for a one-word synonym (or short phrase) meaning "to make one reconsider" or "to make one rethink". This would be used in the context of explaining how an event makes one step back and realize what has passed them by over time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What about simply "gave me pause"?  It sounds a bit
funny, I suppose, but it implies a stopping to 
evaluate (or re-evaluate) things, to reconsider,
to ponder anew.  For example, "When I hit my 
fiftieth birthday, well, let's just say it gave 
me pause.  I began to think about all the
opportunities I had missed, all the dreams I had
failed to pursue."

Comment: This is exactly what my first thought was upon reading the question.

Comment: @delliottg: Does this mean that "great minds think alike"? (LOL, as the young people say nowadays.) Don

Answer (score 2):

"Re-evaluate" or "ruminate" can be used in that context.

> From FreeDictionary.com:
>
> ***Re-evaluate*** meaning: to consider again especially with the possibility
>   of change or reversal ex.:"even though itʼs late, if you turn in the paper
>   now, Iʼll reevaluate your final grade in the class"
>
> ***Ruminate*** meaning: To turn a matter over and over in the mind. To chew
>   cud. v.tr. To reflect on over and over again.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the expression "disabuse" here if the person's original notion was erroneous by your way of thinking.

> disabuse (vb. usually followed by *of* ): to rid (oneself, another person, etc) of a mistaken or misguided idea; set right.

For example,

*After receiving so many condolence cards, I was disabused of the notion that people are inherently apathetic.*

*I disabused her of the belief that mowing the lawn is easy.*

"Disabuse" requires an object, so it wouldn't work if you were trying to make a person re-think, as in re-learn how to interpret the world. In that case, a word like "[liberated](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/liberate?__utma=1.378899234.1355068909.1356207105.1356207844.24&__utmb=1.2.10.1356207844&__utmc=1&__utmx=-&__utmz=1.1355679049.16.5.utmcsr=google%7Cutmccn=%28organic%29%7Cutmcmd=organic%7Cutmctr=%28not%20provided%29&__utmv=-&__utmk=49845286)" might be better.